# How do I fix unexpected character after line continuation character?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to list the file names from Documents directory and when I run the code I get this error: "unexpected character after line continuation character"

I have typed "r" before the path but still not working.

import os
def listig_files(dirname):
    os.scandir(r"C:\Users\migue\Documents\")
        for entry in it:
          if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_file():
              print(entry.name)
After I made the corrections I get the following result:

runfile('C:/Users/migue/Downloads/Python Scripts/rename files from a list.py', wdir='C:/Users/migue/Downloads/Python Scripts')

Answer (score 1):

The line that is causing the problem is

```
def listig_files(C:\Users\migue\Documents):
```

In Python `\` is the "line continuation character" meaning you can use it to break a statement across multiple lines. But it must be the last character on a line.

That's why you're getting the slightly unhelpful message — you have a line continuation character `\` followed by another character.

The function definition should contain a parameter *name* in that location, which you can then use within the function.

```
import os

def listing_files(path_name):
    with os.scandir("r", path_name)as: 
        for entry in it:
            if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_file():
                print(entry.name)
```

Then you could call the function with

```
listing_files(r"C:\Users\migue\Documents") # raw string or escapes for \ needed
```

Note the `"..."` around the path while passing it to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
rome=r'C:\Users\Migue\Documents'
def listing_files(r,rome):
    with os.scandir(r'C:\Users\Migue\Documents') as rome:
        for entry in rome:
            if not entry.name.startswith('.') and entry.is_file():
                print(entry.name)
listing_files('r', rome)
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the path:

> os.scandir(r"C:\Users\migue\Documents")